# Много ли провайдеров сейчас закрывают порты кроме 80 и 443?

Tags: провайдер, websocket, порт

Много ли провайдеров сейчас закрывают порты кроме 80 и 443?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду интернет провайдеров вряд-ли, т.к. это повод немедленно обратиться в техподдержку.

Comment: я хочу использовать websocket на других портах, например 1337 и будет ли он работать у всех пользователей

Comment: у всех прям не будет, но вы можете выдать предупреждение, в основном у вас будут проблемы с корпоративными пользователями, вот у них много чего закрыто будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

провайдеры как правило порты 80 и 443 не закрывают, провайдеры вообще не закрываю порты за исключением некоторых случаев, например когда вирусные атаки или борьба со спамом или ddos.

лучше не использовать не стандартные порты иначе у ваших пользователей будет много проблем с доступом к ресурсам на этих портах.